# PHPExcel custom named references not calculated

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I have a lof of custom named calculations in a sheet which are used all over the place.

when I load the phpexcel object I can see all the names correctly as array named namedRanges.

However, when the final calculation has to be done, I get the wrong output.
It can not calculate the namedRanges.

lets say I have a name called: func, which only holds the number 20.

in cell A1 I say =func, which gives me 20 in excel.
But it gives me #REF! in phpExcel with:

`$activeSheet->getCell('A1')->getFormattedValue();`

I can not use

`$activeSheet->getCell('A1')->getOldCalculatedValue();`

Because the formula has to be recalculated based on user input first.

If its not supported in PHPExcel, is there any other library that is able to read/write and calculate fast ?

Comment: Named ranges are supported by PHPExcel, but not named formulae.... and unless you use COM with ME Excel itself, or PUNO with Open/Libre Office, you won't find many options capable of evaluating any formulae

Comment: Thanks Mark. Will there be a new release which will support named formulas any time soon?